# How to get payload from this given data?

Tags: php, json, laravel, php-7, urlencode

I am unable to get payload from this data please help me. here is the code

> domain_prefix=leadingdots&environment=prod&payload={"created_at":"2018-07-09 05:10:17","customer":{"balance":"0.00000","company_name":null,"contact_first_name":null,"contact_last_name":null,"created_at":"2018-07-05
>   10:27:47","custom_field_1":null,"custom_field_2":null,"custom_field_3":null,"custom_field_4":null,"customer_code":"WALKIN","customer_group_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f84ff30","date_of_birth":null,"deleted_at":null,"do_not_email":false,"email":null,"enable_loyalty":false,"fax":null,"first_name":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","last_name":null,"loyalty_balance":"0.00000","mobile":null,"note":null,"phone":null,"points":0,"sex":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-06
>   12:59:51","year_to_date":"0.00000"},"customer_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","deleted_at":null,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83355fd52f80","invoice_number":"66","note":"","register_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8aa114","register_sale_payments":[{"amount":1100,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365cae0974","payment_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","payment_type":{"has_native_support":false,"id":"1","name":"Cash"},"payment_type_id":1,"retailer_payment_type":{"config":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb","name":"Cash","payment_type_id":"1"},"retailer_payment_type_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb"}],"register_sale_products":[{"discount":"0.00000","id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365b647272","loyalty_value":"0.00000","price":"1100.00000","price_set":false,"price_total":"1100.00000","product_id":"4d561106-1410-1b93-cc7f-ef04f3306d85","quantity":1,"tax":"0.00000","tax_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f863715","tax_total":"0.00000"}],"sale_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","short_code":"ezl9kt","source":"USER","source_id":null,"status":"CLOSED","taxes":[{"id":"0f867708-803e-11e8-ba42-0adfd74a1555","name":"No
>   Tax","rate":"0.00000","tax":0}],"totals":{"total_loyalty":"0.00000","total_payment":"1100.00000","total_price":"1100.00000","total_tax":"0.00000","total_to_pay":"0.00000"},"updated_at":"2018-07-09T05:10:17+00:00","user":{"created_at":"2018-07-05
>   10:27:47","display_name":"Radhe Shyam
>   Sharma","email":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","name":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","target_daily":null,"target_monthly":null,"target_weekly":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-05
>   11:14:25"},"user_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","version":7602780686}&retailer_id=0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f833351&type=sale.update=

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your request

Comment: r u getting this data from URL?

Comment: yes, i am getting this data on my call back url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode() on "&"` then you will get data in array format. so if your payload string is not at fixed position then you can use `foreach loo`p in which you can find the payload string is present in string or not with help of `strchr()`.

```
 $str = 'domain_prefix=leadingdots&environment=prod&payload={"created_at":"2018-07-09 05:10:17","customer":{"balance":"0.00000","company_name":null,"contact_first_name":null,"contact_last_name":null,"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","custom_field_1":null,"custom_field_2":null,"custom_field_3":null,"custom_field_4":null,"customer_code":"WALKIN","customer_group_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f84ff30","date_of_birth":null,"deleted_at":null,"do_not_email":false,"email":null,"enable_loyalty":false,"fax":null,"first_name":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","last_name":null,"loyalty_balance":"0.00000","mobile":null,"note":null,"phone":null,"points":0,"sex":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-06 12:59:51","year_to_date":"0.00000"},"customer_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","deleted_at":null,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83355fd52f80","invoice_number":"66","note":"","register_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8aa114","register_sale_payments":[{"amount":1100,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365cae0974","payment_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","payment_type":{"has_native_support":false,"id":"1","name":"Cash"},"payment_type_id":1,"retailer_payment_type":{"config":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb","name":"Cash","payment_type_id":"1"},"retailer_payment_type_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb"}],"register_sale_products":[{"discount":"0.00000","id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365b647272","loyalty_value":"0.00000","price":"1100.00000","price_set":false,"price_total":"1100.00000","product_id":"4d561106-1410-1b93-cc7f-ef04f3306d85","quantity":1,"tax":"0.00000","tax_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f863715","tax_total":"0.00000"}],"sale_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","short_code":"ezl9kt","source":"USER","source_id":null,"status":"CLOSED","taxes":[{"id":"0f867708-803e-11e8-ba42-0adfd74a1555","name":"No Tax","rate":"0.00000","tax":0}],"totals":{"total_loyalty":"0.00000","total_payment":"1100.00000","total_price":"1100.00000","total_tax":"0.00000","total_to_pay":"0.00000"},"updated_at":"2018-07-09T05:10:17+00:00","user":{"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","display_name":"Radhe Shyam Sharma","email":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","name":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","target_daily":null,"target_monthly":null,"target_weekly":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-05 11:14:25"},"user_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","version":7602780686}&retailer_id=0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f833351&type=sale.update=';
        $array = explode('&',$str);
        foreach($array as $value) {
            $str2  =  strchr($value, 'payload');
            if(!empty($str2)) {
                $result = $str2;
            }

        }
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
payload={"created_at":"2018-07-09 05:10:17","customer":{"balance":"0.00000","company_name":null,"contact_first_name":null,"contact_last_name":null,"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","custom_field_1":null,"custom_field_2":null,"custom_field_3":null,"custom_field_4":null,"customer_code":"WALKIN","customer_group_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f84ff30","date_of_birth":null,"deleted_at":null,"do_not_email":false,"email":null,"enable_loyalty":false,"fax":null,"first_name":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","last_name":null,"loyalty_balance":"0.00000","mobile":null,"note":null,"phone":null,"points":0,"sex":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-06 12:59:51","year_to_date":"0.00000"},"customer_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","deleted_at":null,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83355fd52f80","invoice_number":"66","note":"","register_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8aa114","register_sale_payments":[{"amount":1100,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365cae0974","payment_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","payment_type":{"has_native_support":false,"id":"1","name":"Cash"},"payment_type_id":1,"retailer_payment_type":{"config":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb","name":"Cash","payment_type_id":"1"},"retailer_payment_type_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb"}],"register_sale_products":[{"discount":"0.00000","id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365b647272","loyalty_value":"0.00000","price":"1100.00000","price_set":false,"price_total":"1100.00000","product_id":"4d561106-1410-1b93-cc7f-ef04f3306d85","quantity":1,"tax":"0.00000","tax_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f863715","tax_total":"0.00000"}],"sale_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","short_code":"ezl9kt","source":"USER","source_id":null,"status":"CLOSED","taxes":[{"id":"0f867708-803e-11e8-ba42-0adfd74a1555","name":"No Tax","rate":"0.00000","tax":0}],"totals":{"total_loyalty":"0.00000","total_payment":"1100.00000","total_price":"1100.00000","total_tax":"0.00000","total_to_pay":"0.00000"},"updated_at":"2018-07-09T05:10:17+00:00","user":{"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","display_name":"Radhe Shyam Sharma","email":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","name":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","target_daily":null,"target_monthly":null,"target_weekly":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-05 11:14:25"},"user_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","version":7602780686}
```

Comment: Thank you So much Bro, may i know your email?

Comment: kapilsamshette@gmail.com

Comment: can you please tell me how to get this field "contact_first_name" from this json ?

Comment: if you want the contact_first_name then use `Json_decode()` . This function will return array. you can get data from that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"created_at":"2018-07-09 05:10:17","customer":{"balance":"0.00000","company_name":null,"contact_first_name":null,"contact_last_name":null,"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","custom_field_1":null,"custom_field_2":null,"custom_field_3":null,"custom_field_4":null,"customer_code":"WALKIN","customer_group_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f84ff30","date_of_birth":null,"deleted_at":null,"do_not_email":false,"email":null,"enable_loyalty":false,"fax":null,"first_name":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","last_name":null,"loyalty_balance":"0.00000","mobile":null,"note":null,"phone":null,"points":0,"sex":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-06 12:59:51","year_to_date":"0.00000"},"customer_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f85287c","deleted_at":null,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83355fd52f80","invoice_number":"66","note":"","register_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8aa114","register_sale_payments":[{"amount":1100,"id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365cae0974","payment_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","payment_type":{"has_native_support":false,"id":"1","name":"Cash"},"payment_type_id":1,"retailer_payment_type":{"config":null,"id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb","name":"Cash","payment_type_id":"1"},"retailer_payment_type_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8ac9eb"}],"register_sale_products":[{"discount":"0.00000","id":"f6f4e5c9-9945-97f0-11e8-83365b647272","loyalty_value":"0.00000","price":"1100.00000","price_set":false,"price_total":"1100.00000","product_id":"4d561106-1410-1b93-cc7f-ef04f3306d85","quantity":1,"tax":"0.00000","tax_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f863715","tax_total":"0.00000"}],"sale_date":"2018-07-09T05:10:14Z","short_code":"ezl9kt","source":"USER","source_id":null,"status":"CLOSED","taxes":[{"id":"0f867708-803e-11e8-ba42-0adfd74a1555","name":"No Tax","rate":"0.00000","tax":0}],"totals":{"total_loyalty":"0.00000","total_payment":"1100.00000","total_price":"1100.00000","total_tax":"0.00000","total_to_pay":"0.00000"},"updated_at":"2018-07-09T05:10:17+00:00","user":{"created_at":"2018-07-05 10:27:47","display_name":"Radhe Shyam Sharma","email":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","name":"leadtesting@yopmail.com","target_daily":null,"target_monthly":null,"target_weekly":null,"updated_at":"2018-07-05 11:14:25"},"user_id":"0adfd74a-1555-11e8-fa42-803e0f8b1095","version":7602780686}
```

This is Json string, you can parse it to array with json_decode() function.

Comment: but how can i get this json from the current string?

Comment: The simplest way just explode it: `$str = explode("payload=", "your_data");
$str = explode("&retailer_id", $str[1]);
$result = json_decode($str[0]);
var_dump($result);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode a raw json payload to an array:

```
$payLoad = json_decode(request()->getContent(), true);

dd($payLoad['created_at']);
```